# Coordinate calculation on a unit sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm writing a first person 3D game and I do not know the math behind what I need. I have 3 angles, a,b, and c.
Angle a shows relation of x and z axis
Angle b shows relation of y and z axis
Angle c shows relation of x and y axis
The direction the player is looking uses all three of these.
Note that z is not always depth, y is not always height, and x is not always width. Though the player may face a different direction, the 3D plane does not rotate. 
If the player is at (0, 0, 0), how can I determine the coordinates of the point exactly 1 unit away from the player? 
I don't need any code, just a formula that shows how a, b, and c are used.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific here.  Usually angles are measured between two lines and/or planes.  What are the angles $a$, $b$, and $c$ measured between?  (Surely it can't be between the $x$ and $z$ axis, as you imply — that would be 90° unless you're doing something really unusual.)

Comment: When looking forward ( no change ), changing angle a pans side-side, b pans up-down, and c rotates. When facing 90 degrees to the side, c pans up/down because you are looking at x as depth, not z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to are called directional cosines. They can be seen in this picture except $a$ would be $\alpha$, $b$ would be $\beta$, and $c$ would be $\gamma$,

[image]

Without explaining multivariable calculus, the best way to do this is to create a vector $v$=$< x,y,z >$ where each component ($x$, $y$, or $z$) is the difference between where the player is looking and where the player is positioned. For example, if the player is at $(2,1,4)$ and wants to look at the point $(4,0,5)$, then the vector is $< 4-2, 0-1, 5-4 >$ which is $< 2, -1, 1 >$. After you have the vectors, use these formulas to find your angles:

$a=cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}})$

$b=cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}})$

$c=cos^{-1}(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}})$

Edit:
If you have the angle but you want the point, then use
$(|v|cos(a),|v|cos(b),|v|cos(c))$ for $(x,y,z)$, where |v| is the magnitude.
In a unit sphere, |v| would be 1, so you would just need to use $(cos(a),cos(b),cos(c))$

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the inverse of what I'm asking. I give the angle (assume player location is (0, 0, 0) and need a point where he's looking. I apologize for the unclarity

Comment: Oh, my bad, Give me a sec and I'll fix it.

Comment: Oh, that makes it simpler. x = cos(a), y=cos(b), and z=cos(c) because the magnitude, which is the square root on the denominator, is equal to one in a unit sphere.

Comment: That can't be right because, at the start, every angle is 0. cos(0) = 1. At the start, I know the player is not facing (1, 1, 1). He's facing (0, 0, 1). Also, (1,1,1) is not on a unit sphere

Comment: Angle c starts from the z axis and goes down, so when the player is facing forward (along the y-axis), z is 90 degree. (it is not complementary to anything like I stated before though, that was my bad)